# How can i rowwise create polygons from records in a dataframe using sf, similar to Postgis

Tags: r, dataframe, polygon, r-sf, rowwise

I've got a table in Postgis which contains the field beginpunt, a geometry field containing a single point.
Next I'll create a 100*100m square which contains the point.
In Postgis I'll use the query below and it works great.

```
select 
*
,st_transform(
    ST_MakeEnvelope(floor(st_x(st_transform(beginpunt,28992))/100) *100,
                floor(st_y(st_transform(beginpunt,28992))/100) *100, 
                floor(st_x(st_transform(beginpunt,28992))/100) *100 +100,
                floor(st_y(st_transform(beginpunt,28992))/100) *100 +100, 28992),4326)  as cbs_begin          
from cbs
```

For a specific reason I want to achieve the same without using Postgis, but do the whole excersise in R.
This is where I get stuck. I can create a single polygon, but my problem is doing it rowwise in a dataframe.

I have the same table (cbs) in R

for simplicity i created a few extra fields:

```
    dput(cbs)  #this is the input dataframe
    
    cbs$beginpunt_rd<-st_transform(cbs$beginpunt,28992) #transform crs
    cbs$begincbsx<-floor(st_coordinates(cbs$beginpunt_rd)[,1]/100)*100 #define origin x
    cbs$begincbsy<-floor(st_coordinates(cbs$beginpunt_rd)[,2]/100)*100 #define origin y
    
    cbs$pol<-NA #create an extra empty field in the dataframe
    tbldata<-st_sfc()  #create an empty table 
    for(i in 1:nrow(cbs)){
      cbs_begin <- st_polygon(
        list(
          cbind(
            rbind(cbs$begincbsx[i],cbs$begincbsx[i]+100,cbs$begincbsx[i]+100 , cbs$begincbsx[i],cbs$begincbsx[i]),
            rbind(cbs$begincbsy[i],cbs$begincbsy[i],cbs$begincbsy[i]+100 , cbs$begincbsy[i]+100,cbs$begincbsy[i])
          )
        ))
      
      if(i<2){tbldata<-cbs[FALSE,]} #create empty dataframe
      tbldata[nrow(tbldata) + 1, ] <- c(cbs[i,1:5],st_sfc(st_polygon(cbs_begin),crs=28992)) #add row to dataframe
    }

dput(tbldata) #this is the output dataframe
```

The code above gives me a (new) dataframe with a field "pol" containing a list with the right coordinates,
but it's missing  the step to make it a polygon or sf object.

I've seen some examples of how it could be done, but I can't get it to work

Edit: the input-table cbs
dput(cbs) result is:

```
structure(list(id = c(9594L, 9520L, 9492L, 83859L, 
                              9438L, 9490L), beginpunt = structure(list(structure(c(5.0499337, 
                                                                                          51.5676501), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0146573, 
                                                                                                                                                     51.5818484), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.08459, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                51.557595), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0129685, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          51.5865527), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0548874, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     51.5164541), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0647628, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                51.5812475), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 5.0129685, ymin = 51.5164541, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    xmax = 5.08459, ymax = 51.5865527), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the output/result table: tbldata
dput(tbldata)

```
structure(list(id = c(9594L, 9520L, 9492L, 83859L, 
9438L, 9490L), beginpunt = structure(list(structure(c(5.0499337, 
51.5676501), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0146573, 
51.5818484), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.08459, 
51.557595), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0129685, 
51.5865527), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0548874, 
51.5164541), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(5.0647628, 
51.5812475), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 5.0499337, 
ymin = 51.5676501, xmax = 5.0499337, ymax = 51.5676501), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), classes = character(0), n_empty = 0L, class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc")), beginpunt_rd = structure(list(structure(c(131616.180272543, 
397688.855374183), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(129178.446528786, 
399280.343643684), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(134014.355256952, 
396559.663404012), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(129064.081985984, 
399804.302704657), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(131933.668374674, 
391991.666781811), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(132651.016139436, 
399196.932221466), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 131616.180272543, 
ymin = 397688.855374183, xmax = 131616.180272543, ymax = 397688.855374183
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:28992", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"Amersfoort / RD New\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Amersfoort\",\n        DATUM[\"Amersfoort\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Bessel 1841\",6377397.155,299.1528128,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4289]],\n    CONVERSION[\"RD New\",\n        METHOD[\"Oblique Stereographic\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9809]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",52.1561605555556,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",5.38763888888889,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Scale factor at natural origin\",0.9999079,\n            SCALEUNIT[\"unity\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8805]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",155000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",463000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Engineering survey, topographic mapping.\"],\n        AREA[\"Netherlands - onshore, including Waddenzee, Dutch Wadden Islands and 12-mile offshore coastal zone.\"],\n        BBOX[50.75,3.2,53.7,7.22]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",28992]]"), class = "crs"), classes = character(0), n_empty = 0L, class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc")), begincbsx = c(131600, 129100, 134000, 129000, 131900, 
132600), begincbsy = c(397600, 399200, 396500, 399800, 391900, 
399100), pol = list(structure(c(131600, 131700, 131700, 131600, 
131600, 397600, 397600, 397700, 397700, 397600), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L)), structure(c(129100, 129200, 129200, 129100, 129100, 399200, 
399200, 399300, 399300, 399200), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(134000, 
134100, 134100, 134000, 134000, 396500, 396500, 396600, 396600, 
396500), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(129000, 129100, 129100, 
129000, 129000, 399800, 399800, 399900, 399900, 399800), .Dim = c(5L, 
2L)), structure(c(131900, 132000, 132000, 131900, 131900, 391900, 
391900, 392000, 392000, 391900), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)), structure(c(132600, 
132700, 132700, 132600, 132600, 399100, 399100, 399200, 399200, 
399100), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The expected output is[image]

Comment: Please add input data to your question so we can replicate your issue. For example, share the results of `dput(cbs)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to enter the following line of code and it should work :

`cbs <- st_sf(cbs, sf_column_name = "beginpunt", crs = 4326)`

Output :

```r
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 5.012968 ymin: 51.51645 xmax: 5.08459 ymax: 51.58655
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>      id                 beginpunt
#> 1  9594 POINT (5.049934 51.56765)
#> 2  9520 POINT (5.014657 51.58185)
#> 3  9492  POINT (5.08459 51.55759)
#> 4 83859 POINT (5.012969 51.58655)
#> 5  9438 POINT (5.054887 51.51645)
#> 6  9490 POINT (5.064763 51.58125)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Edit 1**

Based on @skaqqs' comment, I complete my answer without taking into account his suggestion which normally works very well... but only if the points are arranged in the right order to produce a valid polygon (which is normally the most frequent case).

The original order of the points in your dataframe does not produce a valid polygon: keeping the original order, we get intersecting lines. So, if we choose the classical solution proposed by @skaqqs and draw the polygon, here is the result:

```r
cbs_standard <- st_combine(cbs)
(cbs_standard <- st_cast(cbs_standard, "POLYGON"))
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 5.012968 ymin: 51.51645 xmax: 5.08459 ymax: 51.58655
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> POLYGON ((5.049934 51.56765, 5.014657 51.58185,...
plot(cbs_standard)
```

[image]

To circumvent this difficulty, I suggest another solution by installing and loading the "concaveman" package.

So, please find below the (very simple) procedure to obtain a topologically valid polygon.

```r
install.packages("concaveman")
library(concaveman)

(cbs_concaveman <- concaveman(cbs))
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 5.013 ymin: 51.5165 xmax: 5.0846 ymax: 51.5866
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         polygons
#> 1 POLYGON ((5.0147 51.5818, 5...
plot(cbs_concaveman)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Edit 2**

O.K. we did not understand each other @GeoDude. To follow up on your comment, here is (I hope!) the solution to your problem. You just have to type these few lines of code and it should work:

```r
z <- st_polygon()
for (i in seq(length(tbldata$pol))){
  z[i] <-  st_polygon(list(tbldata$pol[[i]]))
}

sfc <- st_sfc(z, crs = 28992)
tbldata <- st_sf(tbldata, geom = sfc, row.names = 1:length(z))
tbldata$pol <- NULL

tbldata
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
#> Active geometry column: geom
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 129000 ymin: 391900 xmax: 134100 ymax: 399900
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>      id                 beginpunt              beginpunt_rd begincbsx begincbsy
#> 1  9594 POINT (5.049934 51.56765) POINT (131616.2 397688.9)    131600    397600
#> 2  9520 POINT (5.014657 51.58185) POINT (129178.4 399280.3)    129100    399200
#> 3  9492  POINT (5.08459 51.55759) POINT (134014.4 396559.7)    134000    396500
#> 4 83859 POINT (5.012969 51.58655) POINT (129064.1 399804.3)    129000    399800
#> 5  9438 POINT (5.054887 51.51645) POINT (131933.7 391991.7)    131900    391900
#> 6  9490 POINT (5.064763 51.58125)   POINT (132651 399196.9)    132600    399100
#>                             geom
#> 1 POLYGON ((131600 397600, 13...
#> 2 POLYGON ((131600 397600, 13...
#> 3 POLYGON ((131600 397600, 13...
#> 4 POLYGON ((131600 397600, 13...
#> 5 POLYGON ((131600 397600, 13...
#> 6 POLYGON ((131600 397600, 13...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

And the expected output:

```r
library(tmap)

tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to interactive viewing
tmap::tm_shape(tbldata) +
  tm_basemap(server = "OpenStreetMap")+
  tm_fill(NA) +
  tm_borders(col="black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Edit 3**

As a follow-up to your comment @Geodude, please find the fix below. Besides, I removed the for loop to take into account @nniloc's remark (For this, I built the function `polygon_list()` that I have applied to tbldata$pol with `sapply()`).

```r
polygon_list <-  function(x){
  st_polygon(list(x))
}

h <- st_polygon()
h <- sapply(tbldata$pol, polygon_list, simplify = FALSE)
sfc <- st_sfc(h, crs = 28992)
tbldata <- st_sf(tbldata, geom = sfc)
tbldata$pol <- NULL
tbldata
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
#> Active geometry column: geom
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 129000 ymin: 391900 xmax: 134100 ymax: 399900
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>      id                 beginpunt              beginpunt_rd begincbsx begincbsy
#> 1  9594 POINT (5.049934 51.56765) POINT (131616.2 397688.9)    131600    397600
#> 2  9520 POINT (5.014657 51.58185) POINT (129178.4 399280.3)    129100    399200
#> 3  9492  POINT (5.08459 51.55759) POINT (134014.4 396559.7)    134000    396500
#> 4 83859 POINT (5.012969 51.58655) POINT (129064.1 399804.3)    129000    399800
#> 5  9438 POINT (5.054887 51.51645) POINT (131933.7 391991.7)    131900    391900
#> 6  9490 POINT (5.064763 51.58125)   POINT (132651 399196.9)    132600    399100
#>                             geom
#> 1 POLYGON ((131600 397600, 13...
#> 2 POLYGON ((129100 399200, 12...
#> 3 POLYGON ((134000 396500, 13...
#> 4 POLYGON ((129000 399800, 12...
#> 5 POLYGON ((131900 391900, 13...
#> 6 POLYGON ((132600 399100, 13...
```

And by checking one of the polygons, the problem appears to be solved:

```r
tbldata$geom[[3]]
#> POLYGON ((134000 396500, 134100 396500, 134100 396600, 134000 396600, 134000 396500))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @GeoDude, if this answer finally solve your problem, please mark it as accepted to make it easier for other users to find the right answers. If you do not please write what the problem is.

Comment: Nice answer. This results in a point feature class. To convert this to polygon, you can use `st_cast(st_combine(cbs), "POLYGON")`

Comment: Thanks a lot @skaqqs. I had forgotten part of the purpose of the question !

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I learned a lot again, but I'm afraid my question wasn't clear enough. The cbs table was the input table. The resulting dataframe (tbldata) has a field named "pol" with  a list of coordinates which shoud be converted to a polygon. So instead of 1 polygon containing all the points, i want to have 6 (square) polygons. I'll edit the data above.

Comment: O.K. @GeoDude. Please find my answer above as "Edit 2". Let me know if it's O.K. If it is, please mark this answer as accepted  to make it easier for other users to find the right answers. If not, please write what the problem still is. Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery. If I look at View(tbldata@geom) after using your code, I see that each row has all six polygons in them. It just need to be only the single created polygon of that row. Otherwise it grows too big when I use 10000+ records. I think the polygon has to be reduced to tbldata$geom[[i]][[i]]. in some way.

Comment: @GeoDude, Yes indeed you are right. Please find above as Edit 3 the code which  fix this problem. Moreover I took into account nniloc's remark by removing the use of a for loop. To achieve this I built a function and use `sapply()` to apply it to tbldata$pol. Therefore, this code should be more efficient.
Let me know if there is still a problem and if everything is ok please mark the answer as validated. Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @nniloc.

Comment: Wow, @lovalery the third edit works great, I have upvoted the answer. Thanks all for all the effort!

Comment: You're welcome @GeoDude. Glad I could help you. Thanks for your upvote. It would be also great if you could mark the answer as validated because it really makes it much easier for other users to rapidly find the right information on SO. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution. More or less the same as @lovalery but skips the for loops.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(ggspatial)

df_sf <- tbldata %>%
  mutate(pol2 = st_sfc(st_multipolygon(list(pol)))) %>%
  select(-beginpunt, -beginpunt_rd) %>%
  st_as_sf(crs = 28992)

# plot to verify
ggplot(df_sf) +
  annotation_map_tile(zoom = 13) +
  geom_sf(col = 'blue', fill = NA)
```

[image]